# big number implementation(calculator) c++

Tags: c++, sorting, struct

What I need to do is to add this function:

```
void decrement_is(bignum & B);
```

with the capability to subtract 1 from a bignum, completely ignoring its sign,
and not worrying about (but observing) what happens if
the result is negative.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

const bool debugging = false;

const int size = 30;   // I want to make it easy to work with.
// Change to something big later.

struct bignum
{ 
  int digit[size];
  char sign;        // '+' or '-'
  bool ok;
};

// to store the number one thousand six hundred and seventy nine,
// 1679, digit[0]=9, digit[1]=7, digit[2]=6, digit[3]=1, all the rest are zero

void init(bignum & B)
{ 
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 1)
    B.digit[i] = 0;
  B.sign = '+';
  B.ok = true; 
}

void print(bignum B)
{
  if (! B.ok)
    cout << "BAD";
  cout << B.sign;
  bool printed = false;
  for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1)
  { 
    int dig = B.digit[i];
    if (debugging)
      cout << "|";
    if (dig != 0 || printed || debugging)
    { 
      cout << dig;
      printed = true; 
    } 
  }
  if (! printed)
    cout << "0"; }

void addsmall_is(bignum & B, int N)  // _is means "ignoring the + or - sign"
  // N must be small.
{
  int toadd = N;
  int position = 0;
  while (toadd > 0)
  { 
    int sum = B.digit[position] + toadd;
    if (sum < 10)
    { 
      B.digit[position] = sum;
      toadd = 0;
    }
    else
    { 
      B.digit[position] = sum % 10;
      toadd = sum / 10; 
    }
    position += 1;
    if (position >= size)
    { 
      B.ok = false;
      break; 
    }
  } 
}

void main()
{
  bignum X;
  init(X);
  while (true)
  { 
    print(X);
    cout << "\n";
    char c;
    int n;
    cin >> c >> n;
    if (cin.fail())
      break;
    if (c == '+')
      addsmall_is(X, n);
    else
      cout << "+ is the only thing I know how to do\n"; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Why reinvent [GMP](https://gmplib.org/)?

Comment: @MikeDeSimone: GMP is fast--but it's not pretty, not portable, has a crappy pure-C interface, and horrible licensing. There's probably more I've missed at the moment, but those are already more than enough.

Comment: @JerryCoffin What's wrong with the license?

Comment: @NeilKirk: The GPL has multitudes of problems, starting with the simple fact that it appears designed to maximize obfuscation, so almost no two people even agree on exactly what it actually requires--but to the degree that they do agree, the agreement is largely that it doesn't actually accomplish what was intended.

Comment: Your code looks pretty good.  The subtract should be very similar to the add, except you propagate a borrow instead of a carry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void decrement_is(bignum & B) {
    for(int i=0; i<size; ++i) {
        if(--B.digit[i] >= 0) break;
        B.digit[i] = 9;
    }
}
```

As you can see, this ignores the sign.
If B starts off at 0, then decrementing rolls under to a number whose digits are all 9.

And here is subtraction by an assumed positive integer, ignoring the bignum's sign.:

```
void subsmall_is(bignum & B, int N) {
    for(int i=0; i<size && N; ++i) {
        B.digit[i] -= N % 10;
        N /= 10;
        if(B.digit[i] < 0) {
            B.digit[i] += 10;
            ++N;
        }
    }
}
```

When N > B, the result underflows as before, to give (10^size) - (N-B)

Here is full subtraction:

```
void subbig_is(bignum &a, const bignum &b) {
    for(int i=0, borrow=0; i<size; ++i) {
        if(borrow = ((a.digit[i] -= b.digit[i] + borrow) < 0)) {
            a.digit[i] += 10;
}   }   }
```

Addition is very similar, but opposite:
o  a's digit is added to b's instead of subtracted
o  "borrow" is "carry" and is subtracted instead of added
o  checking for < 0 becomes checking for > 9
o  and 10 is subtracted from an overflowed digit, not added

Comment: Thanks man, appreciate it. I just have one more function i'd like to add                                                              **void subsmall_is(bignum & B, int N)
-subtract any small number N from a bignum, completely
ignoring its sign, and not worrying about (but observing)
what happens if the result is negative.**

Comment: Awesome thanks. Ok last one I promise ha. I just need one for function **void add_is(bignum & B, bignum C)

        I need to able able to add one bignum (C) to another (B), completely ignoring
        their signs.**

Comment: @dudicus Adding two bignum's should have been implemented first.  Then implement a constructor that takes an int and makes it a bignum.  Then your "addsmall" would have been a one line function.